# Dimensions of a vector space, formed by solutions to a homogeneous ODE

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces

I'm a high school student and our physics teacher has briefly shown us linear ODEs. I've tried to investigate more, but there's one thing that I keep missing.

I understand that for a homogeneous linear ODE any linear combinations of its solutions is a solution too due to derivative being a linear operator. So if we find enough linearly independent solutions we can express all others as their linear combinations. But how do we know how many we need? So in other words the question is:

How to prove that the number of dimensions of a vector space, formed by solutions to a homogeneous linear ODE (not necessarily with constant coefficients), is equal to the order of the equation? (Is it always true?)

It seems like an easy question but I can't come up with a proof or find one.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: What do your sources say about this theorem? Can you imagine how to construct a linearly independent system inside the solution space? How could you show that any arbitrary solution falls into the linear span of this system?

Comment: @LutzLehmann, our teacher didn't provide any kind of explanation to this. Everything I've tried to find online was too math heavy (I'm a high school student). I understand, that a sum of two solutions is a solution too, as well as a solution multiplied by a scalar. So if we find enough linearly independent solutions, we can express any solution as their linear combination.

Comment: The principal idea is that there is a (linear) bijection from initial values to solutions. From a solution you can reconstruct the initial values, and any initial value (of the state vector) you get exactly one solution. And the set of initial value vectors is a vector space.

Comment: Okay, I've edited the question

Comment: Yes, that is better. Did you learn anything about the order being equal to the number of initial conditions? Or more basic, what a Cauchy or initial-value problem is?

Comment: what I've found is that you can rewrite a nth order linear ode as a system of n first orders.  Let $$y_1 = y, y_2 = y', \ldots, y_n = y^{(n-1)}$$
The initial equation can be written as
\begin{gather*}
y_n' = f(x, y_1, \ldots, y_{n-1}) \\
y_{n} = y_{n-1}' \\
\cdots \\
y_2 = y_1'
\end{gather*}
It feels intuitive that every first order equation needs one initial condition. Because there are n equations we need n initial values. So for an IVP to be solvable, the general solution to the equation, we started with, must have n coefficients in it (one degree of freedom for every initial value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you found in your sources, every $n$th order linear DE can be transformed, in multiple ways, into a first-order linear system $\dot Y(t)=A(t)Y(t)$ of dimension $n$.

In the examples that concern you, that you will see in an introduction, the coefficients of the original DE and thus of the matrix $A(t)$ are continuous and likely differentiable or better. Then the full existence theory applies so that to any initial condition $Y(t_0)=Y_0$ exactly one global solution exists.

The space of initial conditions is simply the full $n$-dimensional column vector space $\Bbb R^n$ (or $Bbb R^{n\times 1}$ if one will leave no doubt on the columns).

In a next step it is simple to confirm with the above points that the map from initial conditions to solutions is linear, and then even more trivially that it is bijective. This then concludes the proof that the solution space is $n$-dimensional.